# Is there a way to fixed the the ring inside diameter size for all screen sizes and resolutions in html

Tags: css

I made a ring with inside diameter 13 millimeters with screen resolution 1280X800, unfortunately, the ring inside diameter is changing when screen resolution is changed. Is there a way to fix the ring inside diameter size for all screen sizes and resolutions.

```css
.ring {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.black_circle {
  border: 5px solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring">
  <div class="black_circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you attach screenshots! I'm not clear what are you asking for

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `13mm` instead of `50px`. It's allowed.

> Pixels (px) are referred to as absolute units because they will always be the same size regardless of any other related settings. Other absolute units are as follows:
>
> - q, mm, cm, in: Quarter millimeters, **millimeters**, centimeters, or inches
> - pt, pc: Points (1/72 of an inch) or picas (12 points)
>
> You probably won't use any of these very often except pixels.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units)

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution. I just used 13mm to width and height.

```css
.ring {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.black_circle {
  border: 5px solid;
  width: 13mm;
  height: 13mm;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ring">
  <div class="black_circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if go to google development and change the screen size like in mobile screen you will see the circle diameter will become less than 13mm what I would like is the 13mm size never change even in mobile size .